# C Implementation of nasm code

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

I'd like to start converting a little nasm project {[synth.asm](https://github.com/in4k/rgba_tbc_elevated_source/blob/master/src/synth.asm), [synth_core.nh](https://github.com/in4k/rgba_tbc_elevated_source/blob/master/src/synth_core.nh)} to c to learn a little bit more about that little soft-synthesizer.

Problem is my asm knowledge is very very rusty, I'm wondering where to start off. I thought maybe one decompiler could help me out but I haven't found anything open-source able to convert these simple nasm listings to c.

Another alternative would be doing the conversion asm->c manually but I'm struggling to understand one of the most simplest functions :(

ie:

```
;distortion_machine
;---------------------------
;float a
;float b
;---------------------------
;ebp: distort definition 
;edi: stackptr
;ecx: length
section distcode code align=1
distortion_machine:
    pusha
    add ecx, ecx
    .sampleloop:
        fld dword [edi]
        fld dword [ebp+0]
        fpatan
        fmul dword [ebp+4]
        fstp dword [edi]
        scasd
    loop .sampleloop
    popa
    add esi, byte 8
ret
```

broken attempt:

```
void distortion_machine(???) { // pusha; saving all registers
    int ecx = ecx+ecx; // add ecx, ecx; this doesn't make sense

    while(???) { // .sampleloop; what's the condition?
        float a = [edi];   // fld dword [edi]; docs says edi is stackptr, what's the meaning?
        float b = [ebp+0]; // fld dword [ebp+0]; docs says ebp is distort definition, is that an input parameter?
        float c = atan(a,b); // fpatan;
        float d = c*[ebp+4]; // fmul dword [ebp+4];
        // scasd; what's doing this instruction?
    }

    return ???;

    // popa; restoring all registers
    // add esi, byte 8;
}
```

I guess the above nasm listing is a very simple loop distorting a simple audio buffer but I don't understand which ones are the inputs and which ones are the outputs, I don't even understand the loop conditions :')

Any help with the above routine and how to progress with this little educational project would be really appreciated.

Comment: `add ecx, ecx` just means multiply ecx by two which make sense if the function is working on, for example `short` samples (so 2 bytes), and length is expressed in samples.

Comment: Please ask only one question in a post.   I'm assuming the question is "How can I convert nasm assembly to C".   "Need suggestions for how to accomplish <X>" type questions or "what does this code do" are off-topic here.

Comment: @Jack Ok, let's assume the routine is modifying a `short*` input buffer , but `loop` is decreasing ecx by 1, isn't? Also, what's the meaning of `ebp` and `edi` in this context?

Comment: A better title could be "C implementation of assembler code"? You are most not looking for a generalized approach, correct?

Comment: @RadLexus Yeah, indeed, my title is a little bit misleading, changing now

Comment: @BadZen “What does this code do” is not off topic as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: 1. `return ???`, nah, the buffer gets modified in-place. 2. `scasd` seems to be used instead of `add edi,4` :) Its "compare" part is never used since EAX is nothing useful, and its result is not used. You forgot the last `fstd`, which stores back the result.

Comment: @RadLexus Reading about `scasd` atm ;) . So... is it far to say the c signature would be something like `void distortion_machine(short* buffer, int length)` where buffer is `edi` and length `ecx`? I still don't understand why that ecx*=2... isn't loop decreasing by 1 ?

Comment: Your input buffer is probably shorts and so its given length must be doubled to get the size in *bytes*, because Assembly is very literal minded! That is a step which you probably won't need in C.

Comment: You will have hard time to convert this one, as it's optimized for size, so for example this routine does several things which makes no sense without the context of the code which is calling it. Like at end `add esi,8`, while `esi` is not even mentioned in comments, and the result will affect caller. For any instruction (`scasd`) use google: "x86 instruction <ins>" (funny, first link went to wrong description including also ESI modification). Here the `scasd` is used as short form of `edi += 4;`.

Comment: @Ped7g I see, so maybe is not a very good idea starting decompiling the audio routines. Maybe I should start with the main loop core synth routine [here](https://github.com/in4k/rgba_tbc_elevated_source/blob/master/src/synth.asm#L218). I started with these one cos I thought maybe they were isolated/testable routines... but I'm probably wrong :)

Comment: No, I think the whole code has to be treated as single entity, ie. the original sub-routines are probably split more on "reuse instructions" base, than on logical-abstraction, or just left-over artefacts from the writing, when they started as original sub-routine and become patched in the process to do other things as well. You probably have to assemble it together in head to get the whole picture at once and rewrite it as single procedure first. It may be even easier just to decode the data structure in memory, and particular math formulas and rewrite it from scratch from that info.

Comment: About the initial size = size*2 .. as the code is working with dword as sample data, I would rather guess it's "stereo" adjustement, than short vs byte sample? (as I think the samples are hold as 32b floats, not shorts or bytes) .. but I didn't check the main code, so I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a bit of guesswork here:

```
;distortion_machine
;---------------------------
;float a << input is 2 arrays of floats, a and b, successive on stack
;float b
;---------------------------
;ebp: distort definition  << 2 floats that control distortion
;edi: stackptr            << what it says
;ecx: length              << of each input array (a and b)
section distcode code align=1
distortion_machine:
    pusha        ; << save all registers
    add ecx, ecx ; << 2 arrays, so double for element count of both
    .sampleloop:
        fld dword [edi]    ; << Load next float from stack
        fld dword [ebp+0]  ; << Load first float of distortion control
        fpatan             ; << Distort with partial atan.
        fmul dword [ebp+4] ; << Scale by multiplying with second distortion float
        fstp dword [edi]   ; << Store back to same location
        scasd              ; << Funky way to incremement stack pointer
    loop .sampleloop       ; << decrement ecx and jump if not zero
    popa                   ; << restore registers
    add esi, byte 8        ; << See call site. si purpose here isn't stated 
ret
```

It's a real guess, but `esi` may be a separate argument stack pointer, and the addresses of `a` and `b` have been pushed there. This code ignores them by making assumptions about the data stack layout, but it still needs to remove those pointers from the arg stack.

Approximate C:

```
struct distortion_control {
  float level;
  float scale;
};

// Input: float vectors a and b stored consecutively in buf.
void distort(struct distortion_control *c, float *buf, unsigned buf_size) {
  buf_size *= 2;
  do { // Note both this and the assembly misbehave if buf_size==0
    *buf = atan2f(*buf, c->level) * c->scale;
    ++buf;
  } while (--buf_size);
}
```

In a C re-implementation, you'd probably want to be more explicit and fix the zero-size buffer bug. It wouldn't cost much:

```
void distort(struct distortion_control *c, float *a, float *b, unsigned size) {
  for (unsigned n = size; n; --n, ++a) *a = atan2f(*a, c->level) * c->scale;
  for (unsigned n = size; n; --n, ++b) *b = atan2f(*b, c->level) * c->scale;
}
```

Comment: Wow, awesome! Thank you very much, hopefully now I'll be able to reimplement the other audio routines to write a little c player of the music. Your c translation totally makes sense :-D

Comment: @BPL Thanks. Note I changed the code to use `atan2f`, the newer C99 function in math.h that handles floats. If you use the original, it will be considerably slower due to double conversion and the slower atan2 in double precision.

Comment: Yeah, sure :) . Right now my main concern is not the speed but more about getting a perfect port (same output than asm version) from that synth (which is precalculating the music at once), after that I'll try to convert it in a real-time synth. In any case, I can see your asm skills are totally amazing. Right now I'm still struggling with `esi`, `edi`, `scasd` in this contenxt, hopefully when I translate the main routine they'll make more sense :D

Comment: @BPL There's no guarantee the atan2f lib call will produce results identical to `fpatan`, but they ought to be close. Believe I got the argument order correct, but if your results are wildly different, try reversing them.

Comment: @BPL One final note and I'm done.  If you have a very good compiler and turn up optimizations, it would not be surprising to see the compiled C run faster than the assembly. The compiler will do tricks like unwinding the loop body so fewer jumps are needed. On at least some `x86` impls, normal branch instructions are faster than `loop`. A key thing will be whether the compiler is able to inline the `atan2f` calls.

Comment: Sure, also, I guess with the first version I'll inline the `atan2f` to be sure the output is correct. Btw, as you can see, the original [code](https://github.com/in4k/rgba_tbc_elevated_source/blob/master/src/synth_core.nh) is optimized in terms of size (final exe can't be bigger than 4k), not in terms of speed (precalculating the whole music at the very beginning) ;-)

Comment: @BPL actually it is almost guaranteed that a "clean" C++ implementation of this synth compiled with -O3 and good compiler will be much faster than this asm, as this is size optimized (just as example the `pusha/popa` hurts performance, and is not needed as only `edi` and `ecx` are modified in the loop and the `loop` instruction itself is very slow). BTW I wonder how would react author of the asm synth of you using his "know how" for your own product.... Maybe you should ask?  To Gene: `loop` will decrease `ecx` in 32b mode, not `cx`.

Comment: @Ped7g As OP said, the code is written to fit in 4k of memory. That explains the instruction choices. Fixed the typo cx->ecx.

Comment: @Ped7g What do you mean my own product? As stated in the post this is just a little learning exercise about small synths + asm, nothing else. If i wanted my "own product" I would choose one of the existing zillion open-source softsynths available, not this one, which is optimized for size, not speed. I just want to **know how this works** behind the curtains. Actually, If I knew properly asm I wouldn't be trying to code it on c/c++ and I'd be reading it straightaway ;-)